# find contours miss some objects

Tags: android, image, opencv

I use the following code to read through all objects that I segmented from my image which should be ordered in row and columns as semi-circle (because of segmentation and morphological processing for reducing noise):

```
Imgproc.Canny(srcImg, srcImg, 50, 150);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/cannyImg.jpg", srcImg);//check

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(srcImg, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0));

//int index = 0;
//double maximc = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(0));
for (int contourIdx = 1; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
    double temp;
    temp = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
    if (temp > 100) { 
                       // condition to differentiate between noise and objects
        Mat drawing = Mat.zeros(srcImg.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.drawContours(drawing, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(255), -1);

        Mat resultMat = new Mat();
        maskImg.copyTo(resultMat, drawing);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/resultImg" + contourIdx + ".jpg", resultMat);//check
     }   
}
```

however, the loop can not read important objects in my image even canny image is correct and can identify all the objects. My questions are: in which order find contours read objects? and also is there another way in Opencv to read through all objects in the image other than find contours? last question i used the size of contours to differentiate between the objects and the noise, so is this Ok or you can suggest other methods.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you attach current output and expected results ?

Comment: If I have a segmented image which is contains 6 objects, only i got for example 4 out of 6 and I can not understand the logic behind how these functions detect objects. Do you think the others are not closed objects even they look closed.

Comment: Yes it is completely possible if the contours are not closed then, it would not be detected , however the question would be more clear with some sample outputs to suggest methods such as erosion , dilation etc to further improve the results